# Finding all real $k$ in cubic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all $k \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the equation $k^3+k^2|k+x|+|k^2x+1| = 1$ has not less then $4$
>
> different solutions which are integers

Attempt: For $k+x\geq 0$ and $k^2x+1\geq 0$

$$k^3+k^2(k+x)+k^2x+1 = 1$$

$$2k^3+2k^2x=0$$

$$2k(x+k) = 0\Rightarrow k=0,x=-k$$

Could some help me to solve it, Thanks

Comment: Are those absolute signs in the question typing errors, or did you just ignore their existence from that point on?

Comment: mo i have jsut open the modulus function for one side.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For $x $ such that
$$\frac {-1}{k^2}\le x\leq -k $$
the equation is satisfied.

we need
$$\frac {1}{k^2}-k\ge 4$$